# Put captcha and anti-spam prohibited words in Drupal forum?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, captcha, spam

Can it be done?

I have a forum based on drupal that keeps receiving a lot of spam, because I don't have a captcha upon threads or comments posting,  nor do I have a list of prohibited words.

Now I couldn't integrate captcha nor could I find a module to deny some offensive words.

Any ideas?

I'm using Drupal 6 .
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [recaptcha](http://drupal.org/project/recaptcha)
- Go to admin settings, recaptcha and enable the option `show captcha admin options on every form`
- Go to the form for which you want to enable the recaptcha, you will have admin settings of recaptcha at the bottom to enable or disable. And enable recaptcha

Answer (score 1):

Use module [recaptcha](http://drupal.org/project/recaptcha) and try to execute SQL command `INSERT INTO captcha_points VALUES ('forum_node_form', 'recaptcha', 'reCAPTCHA');`

Comment: +1 as reCAPTCHA is good, but would steer clear of executing raw SQL if I was OP, it just needs to be set it up at admin/user/captcha